# Skip some classes while running the test coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Is there any way to skip some classes while running the test classes. We are evaluating the test code coverage and we have some classes which are not completed yet so we want to skip these uncompleted classes and generate the test coverage report.

Other than deleting the class / commenting the code, is there any option to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up Test Suites. Look for them in the Test menu in Developer Console.

You can group together a bunch of test classes into a Test Suite, then just run that suite.

I find it particularly useful for deploying between sandboxes: Create a Test Suite for the feature that I'm deploying, and run that on the destination sandbox. Like you, I don't mind if some other tests on the destination fail, I just want to make sure my new feature works.